# Unable to cancel my StreamSubscription based on condition from another StreamSubscription?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two `Stream`s. I want to stop the `stream1` when the `conditionStream` has value that is false. But when **streamSubscription.cancel();** is called `stream1` is not canceled and I have no idea why. Thank a lot for helping.

**Code:**

```
simpleListeningHub<T>(
{Stream<T> stream1, onListening(T), Stream<bool> conditionStream}) {
StreamSubscription streamSubscription;
streamSubscription = stream1.listen((T data) {
  onListening(data);
});

conditionStream.listen((isTrue) {
if (!isTrue) {
  try {
    streamSubscription.cancel();
  } catch (e) {
     print(e.toString());
  }
 }
 });
}
```

Comment: try `await  streamSubscription.cancel();` for the execution of `cancel` to finish.

Comment: did it but still not work, ps. cancel function working fine when i call it outside of  conditionStream.listening

Comment: Is that intentional that you are checking the condition to be false?  maybe you have to change it to `if (!isTrue)` to if(isTrue)` .

Comment: yes sorry for bad naming, about to change it but i did try in two cases(when it true and false), and breakpoints on it to make sure that streamSubscription.cancel() is being called but still even when it called it still not cancel the stream

Comment: @pskink thank you a lot i found the solution, about to answer my own question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution

as @pskink code so i can see the cancel is working fine but what make it look likes it doesn't was because: i did setstate when i click the button to add data to conditionStream. so it did cancel but it rebuild widget and start to listening again after the cancel function is called that why it look likes cancel function not work. Thanks